# Getting nil when trying to convert (NSData from Core Data) to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I set up my core data as follow:

```
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate



func saveIntoCoreData(upload: NSData) {

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var pendingImage = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("PendingImage", inManagedObjectContext: context!) as! PendingImageClass

    pendingImage.pendingImageData = NSData(data: upload)

    var savingError: NSError?
    if context!.save(&savingError) {
        println("saved")
    } else {

        if let error = savingError{
            println("cannot save. error = \(error) ")
        }

    }

}
```

I then pass:

```
       let imageData: NSData! = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage.image!, 1.0)

       saveIntoCoreData(imageData!)
```

I then try to fetch (fetch the results in a TabBarController, different controller from where I save NSData into Core Data) by:

```
var pendingImages = [PendingImageClass]()

func fetchLog() {

    var requestError: NSError?

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "PendingImage")
    if let fetchResults = context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &requestError) as? [PendingImageClass] {
        pendingImages = fetchResults
    }
}
```

Performed the following in ViewDidLoad:

```
let pendingImageDataFromFetch: NSData! = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(pendingImages[0])

    let pendingImageDataFromFetchInImageForm: UIImage? = UIImage(data: pendingImageDataFromFetch)
```

When I try to display pendingImageDataFromFetchInImageForm in an imageView, I am getting an error.

I tried to println to see what is it that isn't going through, and it appears that I am being returned nil for pendingImageDataFromFetch.

Please advise on what is it that I'm missing. Thanks!!!

Comment: what does pendingImages contain when you fetch .. have to try to Log or debug that ?

Comment: Thanks hardik, I did try to Log pendingImages and it contains data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `let pendingImageDataFromFetch: NSData! = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(pendingImages[0])` and replace with

```
let pendingImageDataFromFetch: NSData! = pendingImages[0].pendingImageData
```

You don't need to do anything with an archiver, you just need to extract the image data.

Note that it's also important to check how many results you have rather than just trying to take the first one out.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!! I did check how many results I have, but decided to take the first one out to see if there's actually something there. :)